# Need class for custom config in app.config of collection refering another

Tags: c#, .net

I need custom class for following Custom config in app.config of collection referring another

```
<Tasks >

        <Task Name="Abc" Type="local">
    <TaskName>Abc(note full name goes here)</TaskName>
    <Priority>1<Priority>
        </Task>
        <Task Name="xyz" Type="test">
    <TaskName>xyz</TaskName>
    <Priority>4<Priority>
        </Task>
        <Task Name="123" Type="dev">
    <Task Name>123</Task Name>
    <Priority>5<Priority>
    </Task>
      </Tasks>

      <Activities>
        <Activity Name="coding">
          <Tasks>
            <Task>Abc</Task>
            <Task>123</Task>
          </Tasks> 
         </Activity>
        <Activity Name="planing">
          <Tasks>
            <Task>xyz</Task>
            <Task>123</Task>
          </Tasks> 
         </Activity>
      </Activities>
```

I tried many but I am running to many errors to get list of activities with their tasks please help me

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to serialize this XML?

Comment: I want this collection in my code as list.I am trying to get these Properties by custom class .These values are located in app.config i added section for this  custom values and class for them. But I am getting many errors in that Class

Comment: Cant add code as it is too long I am unable to add it.Can you please give me any sample working class for above structure.

Comment: somebody please reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML structure can be represented by this class. Your XML structure is quite inconsistent. If you want a class structure as accurate as possible, then please fix your XML.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Activity> activities = new List<Activity>();
    }
}

public class Activity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Priority Priority { get; set; }
}

public class Priority
{
    public string Name { get; set; }//--or however you want to structure this class, this could also be an enum
}
```

Comment: I found solution i followed link http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/nested-configurationelementcollections.118146/ and https://nconfiggen.codeplex.com/ also will be used to generate classes for custom config Thanks for help